# How do I disable automatic DivX update popups on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, divx

Occasionally when I start viewing a video, an annoying popup dialog promps me whether to install a newer version of DivX Player.

```
New version of DivX for Mac available
```

As I do not use DivX Player, is there any way to disable the popup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to System Preferences > DivX and modify the "Check for Updates" setting to Never.

Answer (score 12):

Solution from official forum. It works in my case (Setting option to NEVER fails to work)

https://forums.divx.com/divx/topics/divx_update_notifications_still_appearing_on_mac_after_uninstalling

If the URL is dead then here is the transcript

1. Unload the DivX auto-update and media server agents

   `launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.divx.update.agent.plist`

   `launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.divx.dms.agent.plist`

   `launchctl list`

   *(com.divx.update.agent should not appear in the list)*
2. Remove supporting DivX files

   `sudo rm /Library/LaunchAgents/com.divx.update.agent.plist`

   `sudo rm /Library/LaunchAgents/com.divx.dms.agent.plist`

   `sudo rm -rf /Library/Application\ Support/DivX/`

   `sudo rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.divx.*`

--- EOM ---

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You've avoided a common mistake among newcomers: linking to an external resource without giving an adequate description of the linked content. Thanks for including the contents of the linked forum post, and keep it up.

Comment: This has been the bane of my existence for many months. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Abhi Thanks - This is the proper answer after you've already uninstall divX and you have no way to rich the preferences page

Answer (score 2):

It seems the new way is to go to `Applications->DivX (folder)->Preferences`, run that and change the settings for auto-updating.

Answer (score 1):

I found this advice on:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/17048121#17048121

"Here is another sneaky place Divx hides their stuff that "spotlight" did NOT show:
Finder:  HomeFolder/Library/LaunchAgents/com.divx.agent.postinstall.plist"

Indeed I found this item and deleted it. Remains to be seen if popups stop. There are some other suggestions on that discussion, too.

(To show your library folder, hold down the Alt key while clicking Go in the menu bar)

Comment: On my system (OS X 10.9.1) the file that launches the DivX updater is located in /Library/LaunchAgents/com.divx.update.agent.plist

Comment: I had the same issue above. @JensWillyJohannsen suggestion is what helped me and I deleted the `com.divx.*` files

Answer (score 1):

All of the above, especially the #1 Answer, offer good directions for ridding your Mac of the DivX annoyance.  However, I am seeing a number of people who, even after applying these good-riddance tasks, are still being harassed with the annoying DivX Update pop-up.

I may have located the reason for this. They are  DivX embeds over the past months and years.  If like me, you have been using DivX for a number of years, you will have received, and likely downloaded, the updates. That is until you realized you were being subjected to 'App-Abuse' and decided too end it; with no need for DivX.

Only, then you found getting rid of it was worse than getting rid of an hungry mosquito.

I did the cleansing suggested. And saw the removal of a number of files. I then found another post by #Ashtree which called for the removal of yet another divx file. I did so, but found the file to be non-existent.

However, I wondered, 'What else might be in the /Library?' So I looked for com.divx... files that may be hiding there.

**NOTE:** *I tried using the very good Search Tool - Spotlight.  It is a good search tool for finding general files within the USER /folders, but it did NOT find these files.  If one uses the Terminal to conduct a UNIX 'awk' and 'grep' search it may work quite well.  I am a bit rusty on using UNIX shell calls. So, I opted for a directory-by-directory visual search. Just to be sure. *

I found - .divx or DivX - files in the following DIRECTORIES:

- LaunchAgents
- Preferences
- Frameworks

The presence of anything DivX will keep resurrecting the 'UPDATE' pop-up, as long as they were there.

In order to properly 'see' these files - and any other like them - you need to open the Finder and set your VIEW to-> Columns; then set the ARRANGE to-> Date Modified.  This allows you to see different venues of existing DivX or divx files.

I FOUND ---

- the following two files stashed in **/LaunchAgents** - for the months of MAY and APRIL 2016.

MAY
    com.divx.dms.agent.plist
APRIL
    com.divx.update.agent.plist

- the following two files stashed in **/Preferences** - for 2014
  com.divx.unique.hevc.plist
  com.divx.unique.plist
- the following two files stashed in **/Frameworks** - for June 2016
   DivX Toolkit.fremwork
   DivXInstallerUtilities.framework

Simply move the files to TRASH
      NOTE: You WILL be asked to enter your SuperUser/Admin PASSWORD to extract these files.  If you do NOT have this Password, you cannot remove the files.

Close out of Active Programs
Shut your Computer DOWN
Restart .. and you SHOULD BE clean and clear, of the DivX Annoyance.

The proof of this being a totally successful clean will be seen when the next DivX UPDATE cycle is activated.  But I do believe I have thwarted and cleansed the annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Safari and want to uninstall the DivX Player completely, go to *Preferences » Extensions » Uninstall DivX*.

Comment: The user asked how to to auto-updates, not remove the app

Comment: @Lizz The OP also said that they don't use the DivX player at all, so this could be an option regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the Never Update option selected in DIVX preferences for about a year and it just ignores it. I suspect DIVX of dodgy behaviour, and it is only just survivng on my computer before being uninstalled, as it is quite a nice player.

I run Mac's activity Monitor whenever I play a Divx movie, and kill the update process whenever it pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you i65 Design for mentioning the other folders that DivX could be hiding in! I deleted everything from Application Support, Launch Agents, Preferences, and Frameworks, but unfortunately the updater wouldn't leave me alone :(  I found out that there is another DivX file that hides in CACHES (cd ~/'Library/Caches/') and it's called: com.Divx.Installer

That bugger in Caches was responsible for reinstalling DivX in my Application Support even after I had deleted (rm -r) it twice from Application Support.

I found the info about DivX in Caches from this site: https://uninstallmacapp.com/divx-removal.html

Hope this helps others!